# Reference for Theorem from Finite Calculus

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I found this relation in a textbook on finite calculus, but it is informally stated. I tried searching for papers in the area, but could not find anything. Where can I can this relation formally stated as a Theorem?

$D=\ln(1+\Delta)$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the meaning of $D$ and $\Delta$?

Comment: @caverac  I assume, $D = \frac{d}{dx}$ and $\Delta f =  f(x+1)-f(x)$

Comment: Let me know if you find my reply useful

Comment: Please try and be more clear when writing questions in the future. Lacking too much context and other details is one of the criteria for questions to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to showing that

$$
e^{D}f(x) = (1 + \Delta)f(x) = f(x) + [f(x + 1) - f(x)] = f(x + 1)
$$

Call $\epsilon = 1 / n$, for some integer $n$, then

$$
e^D = (e^{\epsilon D})^n \tag{1}
$$

Now, note that for large $n$

$$
f(x + \epsilon) \approx f(x) + \epsilon f'(x) \tag{2}
$$

therefore

$$
e^{\epsilon D}f(x) = \left(1 + \epsilon D + \cdots\right)f(x) \approx f(x) + \epsilon Df(x) = f(x) + \epsilon f'(x) \stackrel{(2)}{=} f(x + \epsilon) \tag{3}
$$

Going back to Eq. (1)

$$
e^Df(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty}(e^{\epsilon D})^nf(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(x + n\epsilon ) = f(x + 1)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The proof given using $\epsilon = 1 / n$ is not completely valid. It fails because the approximation $f(x + \epsilon) \approx f(x) + \epsilon f'(x)$ does not have error bounds. The bounds are required to ensure convergence in the last step. However, that is not how $e^{D}f(x) = (1 + \Delta)f(x)$ should be viewed. It is a **formal** relation. The actual steps are $$e^{D}f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty D^n f(x)/n!= f(x+1) = f(x) + [f(x + 1) - f(x)] = (1 + \Delta)f(x).$$ The infinite sum uses Taylor series formally without convergence concerns. This is a standard result from the "Calculus of Finite Differences".